# iptables: block incoming traffic just for an apache VirtualHost domain

Tags: apache, iptables

I am running an Ubuntu Server with Apache 2.4.7 and iptables 1.4.21.

Currently, I am hosting three domain names on my apache server using VirtualHost because I only have one IP address.

I was wondering if there is a way to use iptables to block an IP from reaching domain1.com, while allowing the same IP to reach domain2.com and domain3.com.

I am a n00b, so have patience with me, thank you! :)

Thank you for your replies!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that instead of using iptables, using the Apache config. Put on your VirtualHost apache config something like this:

```
order Allow,Deny
Deny from x.x.x.x
Allow from All
```

Of course this will only work if you have module installed and enabled.

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-modsecurity
sudo a2enmod mod-security
```

Don't forget to restart the service after changes.

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```